# Why client application doesn't get the list of the file from server directory?

Tags: java, sockets, stream, client-server, client

In my client server application I am trying to print out the list of the file from the server's current directory. In this moment, my program is able to retrieve the name of the files and display, but the problem is, the **result** (with the list of the file) gets displayed in the server window what I don't expect.

I want that as soon as I send the corresponding command (from client side) it should give back the listed files in the same window (in client side).

The code I am working on is:

Server class:

```
package server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class AreaServer {

    private static final int PORT = 8000;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int port = PORT;
        if (args.length == 1) {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        new AreaServer(port);
    }

    public AreaServer(int port) {

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error in creation of the server socket");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        while (true) {
            try {

                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();


                DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());


                while (true) {

                    String commandPWD = inputFromClient.readUTF();

                    String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

                    outputToClient.writeUTF(workingDir);

                    String commandGetList = inputFromClient.readUTF();
file)
                    File fileList = new File(".");
                    getFiles(fileList);//method calling

                    outputToClient.writeUTF(fileList.toString());

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void getFiles(File fileList) {

        File[] listOfFile = fileList.listFiles();

        for (File f : listOfFile) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(f.getName());

            }
            if (f.isFile()) {
                System.out.println(f.getName());

            }

        }

}
}
```

Client class:

```
   package clint;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class AreaClient {

        private static final int PORT = 8000;
        private static final String SERVER = "194.47.46.146";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String server = "localhost";
            int port = PORT;

            if (args.length >= 1) {
                server = args[0];
            }
            if (args.length >= 2) {
                port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            }

            new AreaClient(server, port);
        }

        public AreaClient(String server, int port) {
            DataInputStream inputFromServer;
            DataOutputStream outputToServer;

            try {

                Socket socket = new Socket(server, port);

                inputFromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                outputToServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter pwd command: ");
                while (sc.hasNext()) {

                    String commandPWD = sc.nextLine();

                    outputToServer.writeUTF(commandPWD);
                    outputToServer.flush();

                    String workingDir = inputFromServer.readUTF();

                    System.out.println("Working directory is: " + workingDir);

                    System.out.println("Enter getList command: ");
                    String commandGetList = sc.nextLine();

                    outputToServer.writeUTF(commandGetList);
                    outputToServer.flush();


                    String listedFileFromSErver = inputFromServer.readUTF();

                    System.out.println("You have the following files in the server directory: " + listedFileFromSErver);

                }
                inputFromServer.close();
                outputToServer.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's printing out the list of files because your getFiles method says to

```
if (f.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println(f.getName());

        }
        if (f.isFile()) {
            System.out.println(f.getName());

        }
```

Comment: You missunderstood my point. I want to print out the list of file in my client side, not in server side. The problem is , at this moment the list of file is displaying in the server window.

Comment: You're code explicitly tells it to print server side. If you want your client to print it out you'll need to construct a string and send it back for the client to print.